# Clicking links in custom listview

Tags: android, listview, twitter

I'm attempting to put together a library for Twitter feeds and I've got most of it working, but I'm running into an issue where links in my text are crashing when clicked, and I wanted to see if anyone could point me in the right direction for fixing this.

The main text field of my tweet is defined in XML as this:

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/TweetUITweetTextTextView"
    android:padding="@dimen/tweetTextPadding"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TweetUIUserProfileImageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TweetUIUsernameTextView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="@null" />
```

And this is located inside of a relative layout that I expand into a custom "TweetView" class.

The TweetView takes a Tweet Object that is basically a set of strings that contain the information parsed from a JSON query and sets those strings (In this case, the main text from the Tweet with anchor tags and whatnot from the URL metadata in the Twitter JSON feed) to the textview with this:

```
      if( tweet.tweetText != null && tweet.tweetText != "" )
            tweetTextTextView.setText( Html.fromHtml( tweet.tweetTextWithLinks ) );
        else
            tweetTextTextView.setText( "" );
```

As for my error stack on crash, I have this:

```
 05-30 14:42:22.206: E/InputEventReceiver(22150): Exception dispatching input event.
 05-30 14:42:22.206: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:944)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:931)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:212)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7536)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
 05-30 14:42:22.216: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22150):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
 .....
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you pass "wrong" context in your adapter. E.g. application context instead of activity context.

Comment: Oh, whoops :p That was it. Thanks!